# Distance between a point and an empty set: meaning and value?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

On page 253 in General Topology by R Engelking:

> The distance $\rho(x, A)$ from a point $x$ to a set $A$ in a metric space $(X,\rho)$ is defined by letting $\rho(x, A) = \text {inf}\ {\{\rho(x, a) : a \in A}\},\ \text {if}\ A \ne \emptyset, \text {and}\ \rho(x, \emptyset) = 1$.

Why $\rho(x, \emptyset) = 1$? I mean:

1- What $\rho(x, \emptyset)$ means?

2- Why it is equal to $1$?

Comment: it is equal to $1$ as a matter of convention. Another convention is that $\inf\emptyset=\infty$ so one could have set $\rho(x, \emptyset) = \infty$. (Note that if $A$ is empty then so is $\{\rho(x,a):a\in A\}$.) But if one insists that the distance $\rho$ takes only finite values, not $\infty$, then one would settle for something smaller that $\infty$ (but positive) like $1$. It is not uncommon to replace a given metric with one that is bounded by $1$ anyway.

Comment: Although this is putatively a matter of convention, there is another convention which seems more sensible to me, namely that the domain of the function $\rho(x,A)$ should not allow that $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: @LeeMosher - your latter suggestion of convention is deleting the entire question, though it is more sensible to me too that is $A= \emptyset$ should not be in the domain. By if $\rho(x, \emptyset)$ comes to board what does it mean at all, and why the convention is to put it equal to 1 (what are the consequences it can make by number 1)?

Comment: What value can $\rho$ take in that context? Maybe it is defined such that $0\le\rho\le 1$?

Comment: @A.G.: No mention at all that is bounded - you mean that $\rho(x, \emptyset)$ is the max value of $\rho$? If so, why?

Comment: @Edi Maybe in order to somehow mark that all points are *far away* from the empty set. I guess he may need to exclude the empty set when the distance is small, for example, $\rho\to 0$. It is purely for convenience I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance $\rho(x,A) = \inf\{\rho(x,a) \mid a \in A\}$ is usually known as the Hausdorff distance and also generalises nicely to a distance between two sets.

Now, what should $\rho(x,\emptyset)$ be? Intuitively, $\rho(x,A)$ gives the smallest distance between $x$ and any element in $A$. But since there are no elements in $\emptyset$, it makes some sense to let $\rho(x,\emptyset)$ be as big as possible, i.e. $\rho(x,\emptyset) = \infty$. This also corresponds to the practice of defining $\inf \emptyset = \infty$ which is common in other areas of mathematics as well.

When we have any metric $\rho$, we can define the bounded metric corresponding to $\rho$ by
$$\overline{\rho}(x,y) = \min\{\rho(x,y),1\},$$
where $1$ is chosen fairly arbitrarily as the bound, but is an often used value. With such a bounded metric, $1$ is in fact the largest possible value, so in this setting it would make sense to let $\rho(x,\emptyset) = 1$.

So why does the author define $\rho(x,\emptyset) = 1$? Without reading the text, I don't know, but at the end of the day, it can be defined as you like. Maybe the author has in mind some bounded metric, or maybe they are just trying to avoid dealing with infinity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got all what I wanted, except for $\inf \emptyset = \infty$ definition. Would you please help me why this definition is so (in an easy way to understand)?

Comment: @Edi $\inf A$ means the greatest lower bound of $A$, but since any number is a lower bound for $\emptyset$, the *greatest* lower bound can not be any finite number, so it must be $\infty$. Note that this is not a universal definition, but is often adapted.

Comment: This def'n comes from §4.1 in Engelking, which has only a couple uses of the concept of distance between point and set: one is that in metric spaces, closed implies $G_\delta$, and another is that metric spaces are perfectly normal (as a consequence of the first, and directly via $\rho(x,A)/(\rho(x,A)+\rho(x,B))$).  The statements and proofs of these particular results are slightly simpler with $\rho(x,\emptyset)$ being defined and finite; maybe that's why Engelking chose this definition.